# How to backup a descriptor wallet in bitcoin core?

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet, output-script-descriptors

I know we can do this by menu "File - Backup", but how can we get the private key of the address(or something else we can restore wallet) then write it down or print it out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use the `listdescriptors true` [RPC command](https://bitcoincore.org/en/doc/26.0.0/rpc/wallet/listdescriptors/). It will list all the output descriptors that the wallet consists of, together with their private key material (typically, in the form of xprvs). These descriptors can be imported into another wallet using the `importdescriptors` RPC to get an equivalent wallet.

Comment: The output Json is complicated for memory, but it's printable.

Answer (score 1):

You can backup your wallet on bitcoin using the "backupwallet" RPC or "File > Backup" on GUI

> $ bitcoin-cli -rpcwallet="wallet-01" backupwallet
> /path/to/Backups/backup-01.dat

More information on managing your wallet can be found at https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/doc/managing-wallets.md#14-backing-up-the-wallet

Comment: I don't think this answers OP's question; they're looking for printable data.

Comment: @foolbear if you are looking to get the private key of addresses to print you can use the dumpprivkey "address" RPC

Comment: That doesn't work for descriptor wallets.

Comment: dumpprivkey is for legacy wallet only. @BrandonOdiwuor

Comment: So the only way is backup the whole wallet in Bitcoin Core, thanks. @PieterWuille